# Pesquisar chave de um array e retornar valor

Tags: php

Estou manipulando um arquivo XML grande que quando lido retorno vários array, uns dentro do outro, é possível pesquisar a chave de um array e retornar seu valor? ou um array se existir mais de uma chave?

algo como:

```
    array(
    'bio'=> array(
        'info'=> array(
               'cash'=>'50'
);
    );
```

E algo pesquisar, por exemplo, por **"cash"** ele percorre todos os array e retorna **"50"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/function.array-walk-recursive), exemplo:

```
$array = array('bio'=>array('info'=>array('cash'=>'50')));
function printFind($item, $key){
    if($key == 'cash'){
        echo $item;
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($array,'printFind');
```

**[IDEONE](https://ideone.com/21AzOr)**

Comment: Como seria pra retornar um array ao invés de strings? podem ter vários resultados com a mesma chave

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 vc pode fazer assim https://ideone.com/xklRSv

Answer (score 5):

Você pode pegar as chaves dos Arrays com array_keys($array);

Com isso você pode pegar o retorno e encontrar a chave que deseja.
Depois pegar o valor.

```
$array = array("azul", "vermelho", "verde");
$key = array_keys($array, "vermelho"));
echo $array[$key];
```

Segue um outro exemplo com recursividade.

```
<?php
$array = array("color" => array("azul", "vermelho", "verde"),
               "size"  => array("joão", "maria", "pedro"));

function verificar(array $array)
{
    $keys = array();

    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $keys[] = $key;

        if (is_array($value)) {
            $keys = array_merge($keys, verificar($value));
        }
    }

    return $keys;
}

$valores = verificar($array);
print_r($valores);
?>
```

Comment: Posta um exemplo @Marcondes, sua resposta vai ficar bem mais completa

Comment: Ele não "enxerga" os array multidimensionais, só retorna a chave dos primeiros

Comment: Sim, dai você tem que fazer uma recursividade.... Estou vendo um exemplo aqui...

Comment: Fiz uma atualização com recursividade.

Comment: sei que já tem um tempinho mas teria como pegar somente a primeira chave de cada array?